# Workaround for WITH RESULT SET for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, set, metadata

I have a database (several actually) under SQL Server 2008 running perfectly fine.

Upon upgrading to 2012, I find that none of my stored procedures with dynamic SQL will function without throwing an error.

Stuff like:

```
SET @SQLQuery = ' 
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  p.*
            ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pbd.sku 
                    ORDER BY pbd.sku)
    FROM    Products_BaseData pbd
    LEFT JOIN Products as p on p.sku = pbd.sku
    WHERE pbd.Products_BaseData_productGUID in (
        SELECT ptcprodGUID FROM Products2Categories WHERE ptccatID = @catId
    ) AND pbd.VisibleOnSite = 1
)
-- blah blah --
    WHERE RowNum = 1 '
    + @filter + '
        ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @sortBy = ''0'' then ProductName END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @sortBy = ''1'' then ProductName END DESC
'
SET @ParamDefinition = ' @catId int,
                         @sortBy int'
EXECUTE sp_Executesql @SQLQuery, @ParamDefinition,
                    @catId,
                    @sortBy
```

This results in...

> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXECUTE sp_Executesql @SQLQuery, @ParamDefinition,
>       @catId,
>       @sortBy' in procedure 'jspc_GetVisibleProductsBaseByCategory'  contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set.

Consider? No. I don't want to use result sets. In fact I can't in several circumstances as the data returned may well be different depending on input parameters.

I have tried changing the compatibility level all the way back to 80 and it still throws the error. I tried using "SQLOLEDB" and "SQLNCLI10" in the loopback linked server. Made no difference. I also tried using "System.Data.OleDb" as the provider for the connection string in `web.config`.

I do not want to go through several hundred stored procedures in multiple databases and edit them one by one and go through testing each one.

What do I need to do to get a SQL Server 2008 database to function **AS IS** on SQL Server 2012? I mean there has to be a flag or something I can set to tell 2012 to run them as is?

Edit...
Adding code showing a typical call from C#:

```
try {
    using ( SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection( StrConn ) ) {
        SqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "jspc_GetVisibleProductsBaseByCategoryPaged";
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlConn;
        SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@catId", catId );
        SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@sortBy", sort );
        SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@filter", filter );
        SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@PageStart", page );
        SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@ItemCount", ItemCount );
        SqlDA.SelectCommand = SqlCmd;
        SqlDA.Fill( dtRetVal );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try explicitly defining the column names in the cte expression like `WITH CTE (Col1 , Col2 , Col3) AS ......` and see what happens. On a side note CTE will not work in any compatibility level older than 90, it was introduced in 2005 :) . compatibility level 80 is Sql server 2000 , CTE did not exist back then.

Comment: Thank you, but CTE columns not relevant.  I tried a generic SProc that simply executed a very basic SELECT with dynamic sql.  Same error so CTE not a factor in the error.  And yes, CTE won't work < 90.  But I went for 80 with the generic test SProc as it should have executed in Sql 2000 (and did on a real 2000 install we have here).

Comment: Is [`WITH RESULT SETS UNDEFINED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) causes same error? Also, it's possible that [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) or similar procs called implicitly or explicitly on client side?

Comment: When you say you have tried with `SQLOLEDB` and `SQLNCLI10`, from where you are making a call to these procedures ?

Comment: @M.Ali  No.  Those are providers not callable functions/procs.

`EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LOOPBACK', @srvproduct=N'NetSQLSrvr', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'SOMESERVER'
`

Comment: I just tested adding `WITH RESULT SETS UNDEFINED` to the code.  No change in returned error message.

Comment: @Wolfie I know these are providers , I was asking from where (application, web app , SSIS ) you are making call to your procedures ?

Comment: @M.Ali  My bad.  I misunderstood your question.  Calling from a MVC/Class web app also executing the same query in SQL2008 management studio results in the same error so it eliminates the application as a source of the problem.  Its entirely on SQL server 2012 at this point.